# Is Ubuntu One available for Fedora?

Tags: ubuntu-one, fedora

I just wondering why Ubuntu is not developing the Ubuntu One client for Fedora even the closed source one. It will help to broaden the Ubuntu Cloud and revenue generating Ubuntu Music store by introducing the same to Fedora and other Linux distribution. Looking forward to see this happen in near future.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/1008190

Answer (score 9):

Here's a Yum repo with updated UbuntuOne RPMs for Fedora

http://www.maxiberta.com.ar/blog/ubuntuone-packages-fedora

---

**Yum Setup**

Download and install the .repo file into /etc/yum.repos.d/:

```
wget http://www.maxiberta.com.ar/repo/fedora-ubuntuone.repo
sudo mv fedora-ubuntuone.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

Install the ubuntuone-client package and all of its dependencies:

```
sudo yum install ubuntuone-client
```

**UbuntuOne Client Setup**

Connect to UbuntuOne services and authenticate:

```
u1sdtool --connect
```

A popup window will appear where you can register a new user or use an existing account.

The Gnome Keyring will ask you to enter you passphrase in order to securely store your UbuntuOne credentials

The UbuntuOne Sync Daemon will run automatically every time you log in.

That's all! Your ~/"Ubuntu One" directory is now synchronized with your UbuntuOne cloud storage

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The maxiberta link above provides a really old version of UbuntuOne (2.0). The source version at LaunchPad (4.1.91 - https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client) runs on Fedora with the standard ./configure > make > sudo make install commands.

Comment: @Tom - on Fedora 19, it shows as version 4.1.2 :-)

Answer (score 5):

The [UbuntuOne](https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client) client is free software released under the GPLv3.

I don't think that ubuntu developers will do integration work for fedora or other linux distributions, because in principle, the client can already be used. Everything else is packaging and making sure libraries are compatible. This is genuinely a fedora developer task.  See [here](http://thomas.apestaart.org/log/?p=1074) for example for someone trying to use an older version of the client on fedora 11 (the link is from 2009).

Answer (score 1):

The closed source one? There is no closed source Ubuntu One, as far as I'm aware. The one we use in Ubuntu will run perfectly on Fedora, and any other distro, as is. Indeed, I think it should be automatically usable on any free operating system. It just needs to be packaged, and that's Fedoras job, just as packaging SPICE for Ubuntu (which is a very nice software in Fedora), is Ubuntus job.

Comment: If that would have been the case then by that time you could have find any solution on Google. Even Fedora user want to use the 5GB of online storage against 2GB of Dropbox....so I guess still neither code is open nor you find anything on internet.

Comment: It is open and free software written in Python. And I remember seeing that someone was packaging it for Fedora a while ago. I don't know what happened, though.

Answer (score 1):

There may be third-party solutions for various distributions. However, your favorite distribution's solution may not be maintained well. I think interested people should push Ubuntu One developers.

You may help by supporting my bug report.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/951992

Answer (score 0):

http://www.abouthack.com/articles/linux/running-ubuntu-one-on-fedora.html

This article displays how to use ubuntu one on fedora. I have tested this on fedora 16 and it worked

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.