# How do I install Ubuntu One on Fedora 17?

Tags: ubuntu-one, fedora

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is Ubuntu One available for Fedora?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79769/is-ubuntu-one-available-for-fedora)

*(Edited Google translation.)*

I have a new hard drive and installed Fedora 17 on it. My other computers use Ubuntu One, by having either Ubuntu or Windows on them. I'd like to install the Ubuntu One client on Fedora 17 in RPM format, but can not find it anywhere, any ideas?

---

Original spanish question:

#### Como instalo ubuntuone en fedora 17?

Tengo un nuevo disco duro e instale fedora 17 en mis otras computadoras uso ubuntuone, por que tienen ubuntu o windows, pero quiero instalar el cliente de ubuntuone en fedora 17 y el rpm no lo encuentro por ningun lado , alguna idea ?

Comment: Madre mia, don Jesus y todos los Santos, para Ingles, por favor!

Comment: Este es un sitio que funciona exclusivamente en inglés. Por favor, no haga preguntas en español.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79769/is-ubuntu-one-available-for-fedora?rq=1

Comment: @Melon I don't think it's very appropriate to use " don Jesus y todos los santos" on this website considering the assortment of faiths people hold here. With that said, it would be "En ingles" and sierrasdetandil used the wrong conjugation of hacer.